# What would be the missing step in the accumulator for this program?

Tags: python

So I've been assigned to write a program in python that prompts the user to type a word, then deletes letters from the word in sequence. The first letter in the first line, the second in the second, etc.

For example, for "Atlanta":

```
tlanta
alanta
atanta
atlnta
atlata
atlana
atlant
```

This is what I've got and semantically, it's not doing anywhere close to what I want.! I guess it's clear the problem lies in the first and second lines of the for loop. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I don't get the problem statement, can you describe it more?

Comment: @squiguy Will do. Gimmie a sec.

Comment: Also, saying "it's not doing anywhere close to what I would want!" isn't very helpful. Always try to describe (or, better, just copy and paste…) exactly what you want it to do, what it does instead (including pasting an exception with traceback, if that's what it does), and, if it's not obvious, what's different about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
end = word - letter
```

Here, `word` is a string, like `atlanta`, and `letter` is a number, like `2`. What do you expect subtracting them to do?

What you want to do here is get all of the letters of `atlanta` except #2, right? You do that by slicing. With those values, `word[:letter]` will get you `'at'`, while `word[letter:]` will get you `'lanta'`. You should be able to figure out from that how to get what you actually want, `'anta'`.

And once you have `'at'` and `'anta'`, all you have to add is concatenate them, with `+`, and print the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it like this:

You need to loop through the process of printing the whole word except from a letter, as many times as the number of letters that consist the word.

So it would go like this:

```
word = raw_input("Enter word:")

for i in range(len(word)):      # loop as many times as the number of letters
    print word[:i] + word[i+1:] # print all letters but the current iteration's
```